# How to insert where condition in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I will pass the query into this function `query("SELECT * FROM table_name");`

And the function is

```
public function query($sql) {

        $resource = mysql_query($sql, $this->link_web);

        if ($resource) {
            if (is_resource($resource)) {
                $i = 0;

                $data = array();

                while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($resource)) {
                    $data[$i] = $result;

                    $i++;
                }

                mysql_free_result($resource);

                $query = new stdClass();
                $query->row = isset($data[0]) ? $data[0] : array();
                $query->rows = $data;
                $query->num_rows = $i;

                unset($data);

                return $query;  
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            trigger_error('Error: ' . mysql_error($this->link_web) . '<br />Error No: ' . mysql_errno($this->link_web) . '<br />' . $sql);
            exit();
        }
    }
```

I want to add `tenent_id = '1'` in `SELECT` query also for `INSERT` query. Likewise I need to do it for `UPDATE`.

I want to bring the query like this

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE tenent_id = 1 and user_id = 1

INSERT INTO table_name('tenant_id, user_id') VALUE('1','1')

UPDATE table_name SET user_id = 1 WHERE tenant_id = '1'
```

Can anyone give me the idea about how to insert `tenant_id` in select, insert and update

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why would you have `WHERE` in an `INSERT` query?

Comment: its hard to understand.Can you please give more details..

Comment: do you understand what insert and update means? if you insert that means you add new row to database (like you did in second query). when you want to change data for certain id already in database,than that is update.

Comment: I am using common function for all query(INSERT, DELETE and SELECT). And I want to make changes in tenant_id in all table while INSERTING, UPDATING and FETCHING. So i asked the logic to do this

Answer (score 0):

It's better practice to use the correct mysql functions rather than just a query function.

For example, if you want to cycle through many items in a database, you can use a while loop:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE type='2'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    echo $line['id'];
}
```

This would echo all the IDs in the database that have the type 2.

The same principle is when you have an object, using mysql functions, you can specify how you want the data to return. Above I returned it in an array. Here I am going to return a single row as an object:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='1'");
$object = mysql_fetch_object($query);
echo $object->id;
echo $object->type;
echo $object->*ANY COLUMN*;
```

This would return as:
1.
2.
*Whatever the value for that column is*.

---

To insert your data, you don't need to do "query()". You can simple use mysql_query($sql).
It will make life much easier further down the road.

Also, its best to run one query in a function, that way you can handle the data properly.

```
mysql_query("INSERT...");
mysql_query("UPDATE...");
mysql_query("SELECT...");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please don't suggest mysql_* functions as they are officially deprecated.

Comment: I know, over using a single function for a beginner they are sort of necessary. Unless you would like to introduce him to PDO?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is: just add the condition to your query. Call `query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE tenant_id = 1 and user_id = 1")`.

If you're concerned about escaping the parameters you pass to the SQL query (which you should be!), you can either do it yourself manually, e.g.

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE tenant_id = %d", intval($tenant_id));
query($query);
```

Or better use prepared statement offered by [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) extension (mysql_query is [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) anyway):

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE tenant_id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $tenant_id);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    // ...
}
```

---

If I still haven't answered your question, you can use a library to handle your queries, such as [dibi](http://dibiphp.com/en):

```
$result = dibi::query('SELECT * FROM [table_name] WHERE [tenant_id] = %i', $id);
$rows = $result->fetchAll(); // all rows
```

**The last option is what I would use**, you don't need to write your own query-handling functions and get query parameter binding for free. In your case, you may utilize building the query gradually, so that the WHERE condition is not part of your basic query:

```
$query[] = 'SELECT * FROM table_name';
if ($tenant_id){
    array_push($query, 'WHERE tenant_id=%d', $tenant_id);
}
$result = dibi::query($query);
```

Comment: I got your idea but i have 1000s of mysql query. i cant edit "where condition" in all queries . using the function QUERY() i want to make the changes.

Comment: @user2269905 Dibi would solve your problem by doing `$query = array($query); array_push($query, 'WHERE ...')` or so. If you don't use ORDER BY or  something that comes after WHERE, just append the WHERE condition to your query and handle inserts as a special case by another function. There's really no other solution - you don't want to implement a MySQL query parser yourself.